# How to refesh individual cell/row without re-rendering the entire table using ngx-datatable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatable, ngx-datatable

I'm trying to update a row/cell of ngx-datatable as it comes from the socket. But when the data comes from socket the whole table is refreshed. I don't want to refresh the whole table as I'm calling a complex function through every cell. I am using angular 8

```
        <ngx-datatable [rows]="dataRows"  [sorts]="sortList" [externalSorting]=false rowHeight="auto" >

            <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let column of columnList;let i = index"  name="{{column.label}}" prop="{{column.key}}" [comparator]="sortComparator" >
                <ng-template let-row="row" let-rowIndex = "rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    <div [matTooltip]="column.type==='tempIcon' ? (returnTooltip(dataRows[i].temp_icon)) : null">
                        <div [cdkPortalOutlet]="selectTemplate(row,column,tempData[rowIndex],columnList[i],i)" ></div>
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ngx-datatable>
```

Here I am trying to dynamically get the column from a list. But for a session the columns won't change. The problem is with the selectTemplate function. I use a socket to update the row in dataRows. when i update it, the table re-renders and calls the selectTemplate function over 760 time. which is really consuming power. It also makes the whole page slow as new data comes every few seconds.

This is how I get data from socket. The lastData is passed to the inner component every time a change occurs. Initial data is also passed through lastData.

```
this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer)=>{
          this.socket.on('message',data=>{
              observer.next(data);
          });
      });
      this.dataSource.subscribe(data=>{
          this.lastData = [data];
          this.combineData();
          console.log('new data',this.lastData);
      });
```

Comment: Any example code?

Comment: Please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I have added some extra details .Can you please check?